# PHP Online Exam

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to build an Online Exam System. I want to fetch the questions from the data base and display them one by one. I mean, users click 'next' to see the next question. I want to use JQuery. Any ideas?

Here is my PHP Code

```
$getTests = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM grammar_test WHERE active = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
$getTests->execute(array(1));
$rowTests = $getTests->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
```

The database has more than 20 Questions, but I want only 20 random questions.

Here is the HTML (Trancated to 2 fieldsets but they are actually 20)

```
<form action="" class="grammar-test-form " method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

<fieldset id="first">
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<h4>1. '.$rowTests['instructions'].'</h4>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['question'])){ echo '<h4>'.$rowTests['question'].'</h4>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_1'].'<br/>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_2'].'<br/>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_3'].'<br/>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_4'].'<br/>';}?>
    <hr/>
    <button class="next_btn btn btn-3d btn-green" name="next" type="button">Next &raquo;</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<h4>2. '.$rowTests['instructions'].'</h4>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['question'])){ echo '<h4>'.$rowTests['question'].'</h4>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_1'].'<br/>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_2'].'<br/>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_3'].'<br/>';}?>
    <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_4'].'<br/>';}?>
    <hr/>
    <button class="pre_btn btn btn-3d btn-green" name="previous" type="button">Previous</button>
    <button class="next_btn btn btn-3d btn-green" name="next" type="button">Next &raquo;</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the JQuery to move from one fieldset to another

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".next_btn").click(function() { 

        $(this).parent().next().fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).parent().css({
        'display': 'none'
        });


        $('.active').next().addClass('active');
        });
        $(".pre_btn").click(function() { 
        $(this).parent().prev().fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).parent().css({
        'display': 'none'
        });


        $('.active:last').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Everything works fine. The problem is one question is selected and repeated 20 times. I want to get 20 different questions. Any Idea?
There is the idea of while loop, but I get problems with the first and the last fieldsets because for the first, it has only one button (Next), the next 18 have 2 buttons (Next and Previous), the last one has 2 buttons (Previous and Submit)

Comment: For problem "The problem is one question is selected and repeated 20 times": check if SQL query gives 20 different questions. I think is something wrong with loop, maybe takes same question id, try foreach. If you can give more code for more accurate answer please.

Comment: Please make your title describe a unique problem.

Comment: _"Everything works fine. The problem is"_ Doesn't work fine then, does it? :)

Comment: By the way, props for using PDO and parameters. You'd be amazed how few people do.

Comment: How are you looping through `$rowTests`? If you're getting 20 of the same results, it's likely that there is something wrong in your loop.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @UgniusMalūkas that's all the code I have managed, unfortunately. And yea, it gets one ID but the Query looks ok.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit some bit of grammar issue but thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: why you don't loop over the results and do simple condition , if id = 1 then preview next input only , else if equal 20 preview previous and submit else preview next and previous

Comment: @HassanAhmed the database table has more than 100 questions. The query selects 20 at random. I am thinking that it is possible that the 1st question has id #90, the second #45 the last #1. Because its random

Comment: you are fetching your data using the `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` constant ! that's means that your data will retrieved as an assoc array , using for each you can use the key of the loop to control this

Comment: Thanks @HassanAhmed could you show some sample codes if you don't mind? thanks

Comment: I'm curious as to why you expect `$rowTests['instructions']` and `$rowTests['question']` to give you different results each time you output it. Where do you make `$rowTests` contain data from the _next_ row? PHP has no way of knowing that by writing a new HTML `<fieldset>` you intend to advance to the next database result row.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit mangled in the formatting I think. From what I can see though you only called the fetch once (only taking the first row of data).
You will want to do a fetch in the loop to get the next question, and construct that to your html or what have you.

Example #2 here seems to show a good pattern. Do your fetch in the while:
[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

The part I mean from that link:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
  $data = $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
  print $data;
}
```

Added more example... This shows using a loop to get each row (question) and outputting the question. Use this instead of having 20 nearly identical copies of the same code.

```
<?php
while ($rowTests = $getTests->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<h4>1. '.$rowTests['instructions'].'</h4>';}?>
        <?php if(!empty($rowTests['question'])){ echo '<h4>'.$rowTests['question'].'</h4>';}?>
        <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_1'].'<br/>';}?>
        <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_2'].'<br/>';}?>
        <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_3'].'<br/>';}?>
        <?php if(!empty($rowTests['instructions'])){ echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$rowTests['question_id'].'"> '.$rowTests['choice_4'].'<br/>';}?>
        <hr/>
        <button class="next_btn btn btn-3d btn-green" name="next" type="button">Next &raquo;</button>
    </fieldset>
<?php
}//end of while loop
?>
```

I did not include any logic regarding the buttons for first, middle and last questions for clarity.

To deal with first and last question having different buttons, you should be able to conditionally know if a question is first or last (is it #1 or #20) and show or hide the appropriate buttons. You could do this with jQuery or not have PHP create the buttons. Again, your choice.

Comment: This answer looks interesting and informative. Thanks. But I don't quite get it. Could you be a little bit clearer or give an example please. BTW, I hadn't come across PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT. New thing learnt. Much appreciated

Comment: @Neville I've added another example to better show what I mean about the looping for your situation.  Note the **while** surrounds the question, so you only need to have the question coded once, and filled with the data  retrieved from the fetch operation.